# For loop to store many matrices

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a data.frame called core.df_long and a sample of it looks like this:

```
       ID 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
 1   6387   Aa   Ba   Ba  Baa  Caa    B    A  Baa  Baa    B   Ba    B    B    A   Ba    B  Caa   Ba
 2   6403    B  Caa  Caa    B  Caa  Caa  Caa  Caa    B  Caa  Caa  Caa    B    B    B    B    B    B
 3   6408    A   Ba   Ba  Baa  Baa   Ba    A    A    B   Ba    B    B   Ba   Ba   Ba  Baa   Ba    B
 4   6411    B   Ba    B   Ba   Ba    B  Caa  Caa    B   Ba    B    B  Caa    B   Ba  Caa    B   Ba
```

I am trying to make one year matrices that count the frequency of transitioning from one letter rating to the other.

What I've been doing is creating matrices for every year manually as follows:

This step selects the two years I need to analyze, 1996 to 1997, and the ID:

```
#1996–1997
core.df_long9697 <- core.df_long %>%
  select(`1996`, `1997`, ID)
```

This step counts the frequency of unique transitions from one letter to another:

```
res9697 <- aggregate(core.df_long9697$ID, by=list(`1996`=core.df_long9697$`1996`, `1997`=core.df_long9697$`1997`),
                 FUN = function(x) count = length(x)) %>%
rename(Count = x) %>%
arrange_at(1:2, desc) %>%
arrange(match(`1996`, row.order),
      match(`1997`, row.order)) %>%
mutate(i = `1996`,
     j = `1997`) %>%
select(i, j, Count)

> res9697
     i   j Count
1   Aa   A     3
2   Aa Baa     4
3   Aa  Ba     1
4    A Baa     5
5    A  Ba     2
6  Baa  Aa     1
7  Baa   A     2
8  Baa Baa     7
9  Baa  Ba     6
10 Baa   B     5
11 Baa Caa     2
12  Ba   A     2
13  Ba Baa     4
14  Ba  Ba     8
15  Ba   B    12
16  Ba Caa     7
17   B   A     1
18   B Baa     3
19   B  Ba     8
20   B   B    23
21   B Caa    16
22 Caa Baa     1
23 Caa  Ba     1
24 Caa   B    12
25 Caa Caa    19
```

This step creates a matrix using xtabs to illustrate the summary of transitions:

```
res9697 <- xtabs(Count~i+j, data = res9697)

> res9697
      j
i     Aa  A Baa Ba  B Caa
  Aa   0  3   4  1  0   0
  A    0  0   5  2  0   0
  Baa  1  2   7  6  5   2
  Ba   0  2   4  8 12   7
  B    0  1   3  8 23  16
  Caa  0  0   1  1 12  19
```

How could I make a for loop that stores every one year (1996–1997, 1997-1998, 1998-1999, ..., 2012-2013) matrix using the steps I've outlined above?

Furthermore, how would I consider three years? And four years, and so on

An example of what I was doing to consider 3 years is as follows:

```
core.df_long969798 <- core.df_long %>%
  select(`1996`, `1997`, `1998`, ID)
res969798 <- aggregate(core.df_long969798$ID, by=list(`1996`=core.df_long969798$`1996`, `1997`=core.df_long969798$`1997`, `1998`=core.df_long969798$`1998`),
                   FUN = function(x) count = length(x)) %>%
  rename(Count = x) %>%
  arrange_at(1:2, desc) %>%
  arrange(match(`1996`, row.order),
      match(`1997`, row.order),
      match(`1998`, row.order)) %>%
  mutate(ij = paste(`1996`, `1997`, sep = '-'),
     k = `1998`) %>%
  select(ij, k, Count)

res969798 <- xtabs(Count~ij+k, data = res969798); res969798
```

ij are the letter grades in 1996 and 1997, and k is the state in 1998.

```
          k
ij        Aa  A Baa Ba  B Caa
  A-Ba     0  0   0  1  1   0
  A-Baa    0  0   2  1  2   0
  Aa-A     1  2   0  0  0   0
  Aa-Ba    0  0   0  1  0   0
  Aa-Baa   0  2   0  1  1   0
  B-A      0  0   0  1  0   0
  B-B      0  0   1  3 14   5
  B-Ba     0  0   1  1  3   3
  B-Baa    0  0   2  0  0   1
  B-Caa    0  0   1  3  5   7
  Ba-A     0  0   0  2  0   0
  Ba-B     0  0   2  5  3   2
  Ba-Ba    0  0   1  2  5   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily do this with `map` or `lapply`, no need for a loop:

```
library(tidyverse)

# First, I create your example data as a matrix. Depending on your data, this first step might look different.
data_raw <- matrix(c("ID", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013",
  "6387", "Aa", "Ba", "Ba", "Baa", "Caa", "B", "A", "Baa", "Baa", "B", "Ba", "B", "B", "A", "Ba", "B", "Caa", "Ba",
  "6403", "B", "Caa", "Caa", "B", "Caa", "Caa", "Caa", "Caa", "B", "Caa", "Caa", "Caa", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
  "6408", "A", "Ba", "Ba", "Baa", "Baa", "Ba", "A", "A", "B", "Ba", "B", "B", "Ba", "Ba", "Ba", "Baa", "Ba", "B",
  "6411", "B", "Ba", "B", "Ba", "Ba", "B", "Caa", "Caa", "B", "Ba", "B", "B", "Caa", "B", "Ba", "Caa", "B", "Ba"), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)

# Second, I drop the first row (the IDs) and the first line (the colnames), since we don't need them later on
data <- data_raw[-1, -1]

# Third, I map the xtab-command to the column-number in your data
map(seq(dim(data)[2] - 1), ~{
  out <- as_tibble(data[,.x:(.x + 1)]) %>%
    set_names(c("i", "j")) %>%
    count(i, j) %>%
    xtabs(n ~ i + j, data = .)
  return(out)
})
[[1]]
    j
i    Ba Caa
  A   1   0
  Aa  1   0
  B   1   1

[[2]]
     j
i     B Ba Caa
  Ba  1  1   0
  Caa 0  0   1
...

# Finallay, I assign all these list elements to xtab-objects
data_names <- data_raw[1, -1]
for (i in seq(length(data_out))) {
  assign(str_c("res", str_sub(data_names[i], start = -2), str_sub(data_names[i + 1], start = -2), sep = ""), data_out[[i]])
}

res0001
     j
i     B Ba Caa
  Ba  1  0   0
  Baa 0  1   0
  Caa 1  0   1

str(res0001)
 'xtabs' int [1:3, 1:3] 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ i: chr [1:3] "Ba" "Baa" "Caa"
  ..$ j: chr [1:3] "B" "Ba" "Caa"
 - attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = n ~ i + j, data = .)

# A solution for three years
map(seq(dim(data)[2] - 2), ~{ # for four years the '-2' becomes '-3'
  out <- as_tibble(data[,.x:(.x + 2)]) %>% # for four years the '+2' becomes '+3'
    set_names(c("i", "j", "k")) %>% # for four years you have to add letter 'l'
    mutate(ij = str_c(i, j, sep = "-")) %>% # for four years it's 'ijk = str_c(i, j, k, sep = "-")
    count(ij, k) %>% # for four years it's 'ijk, l'
    xtabs(n ~ ij + k, data = .) # for four years it's 'n ~ ijk + l'
  return(out)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. The output with the full dataset only returns 1s and 0s. It's not counting the frequency.

Comment: My bad! The `unique()` is unnecessary. I'll edit the code.

Comment: Perfect! It works now. Could I take this to a higher order and make matrices that have x & x+ 1 and transition to x + 2? So instead of considering only two years, I consider three. i, the row name,  becomes "i-j", and j, the column name becomes k. An example is, given 1996 = Aa (i) and 1997 = Baa (j), what is the frequency of transitions to Caa (k) in 1998?

Comment: I guess the solution could be expanded easily. Could you add an example output to your question so that we're on the same page?

Comment: I've ammended my question with an example for considering three years

Comment: I also noticed that your solution omits one ID. I have 155 unique IDs but your code results in only 154 being counted for every matrix.

Comment: Probably that's because of the `data <- data_raw[-1, -1]` line. In my example the first row is just the columnnames. If your data is a dataframe, you only need `data_raw[,-1]`.

I've added the three years solution above. Though I don't think that this approach is dynamically scalable...

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a list of data frames or matrices with `lapply` iterating across a `seq` of your number of columns, using base R:

**Data**

```
txt <- '      ID 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013
 1   6387   Aa   Ba   Ba  Baa  Caa    B    A  Baa  Baa    B   Ba    B    B    A   Ba    B  Caa   Ba
2   6403    B  Caa  Caa    B  Caa  Caa  Caa  Caa    B  Caa  Caa  Caa    B    B    B    B    B    B
3   6408    A   Ba   Ba  Baa  Baa   Ba    A    A    B   Ba    B    B   Ba   Ba   Ba  Baa   Ba    B
4   6411    B   Ba    B   Ba   Ba    B  Caa  Caa    B   Ba    B    B  Caa    B   Ba  Caa    B   Ba'

core.df_long <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**`lapply` + `seq`**

```
df_list <- lapply(seq(2, ncol(core.df_long)-1), function(x) {      
  sub_df <- core.df_long[,c(1, x:(x+1))]
  agg_df <- setNames(aggregate(ID ~ ., sub_df, length), c("i", "j", "Count"))
})

head(df_list)
# [[1]]
#    i   j Count
# 1  A  Ba     1
# 2 Aa  Ba     1
# 3  B  Ba     1
# 4  B Caa     1
# 
# [[2]]
#     i   j Count
# 1  Ba   B     1
# 2  Ba  Ba     2
# 3 Caa Caa     1
# 
# [[3]]
#     i   j Count
# 1 Caa   B     1
# 2   B  Ba     1
# 3  Ba Baa     2
# 
# [[4]]
#     i   j Count
# 1  Ba  Ba     1
# 2 Baa Baa     1
# 3   B Caa     1
# 4 Baa Caa     1
# 
# [[5]]
#     i   j Count
# 1  Ba   B     1
# 2 Caa   B     1
# 3 Baa  Ba     1
# 4 Caa Caa     1
# 
# [[6]]
#     i   j Count
# 1   B   A     1
# 2  Ba   A     1
# 3   B Caa     1
# 4 Caa Caa     1
```

And for `xtabs`, simply add a line in anonymous function:

```
df_list <- lapply(seq(2, ncol(core.df_long)-1), function(x) {      
  sub_df <- core.df_long[,c(1, x:(x+1))]
  agg_df <- setNames(aggregate(ID ~ ., sub_df, length), c("i", "j", "Count"))
  xtabs(Count ~ i + j, data = agg_df)
})

head(df_list)

# [[1]]
#     j
# i    Ba Caa
#   A   1   0
#   Aa  1   0
#   B   1   1
# 
# [[2]]
#      j
# i     B Ba Caa
#   Ba  1  2   0
#   Caa 0  0   1
# 
# [[3]]
#      j
# i     B Ba Baa
#   B   0  1   0
#   Ba  0  0   2
#   Caa 1  0   0
# 
# [[4]]
#      j
# i     Ba Baa Caa
#   B    0   0   1
#   Ba   1   0   0
#   Baa  0   1   1
# 
# [[5]]
#      j
# i     B Ba Caa
#   Ba  1  0   0
#   Baa 0  1   0
#   Caa 1  0   1
# 
# [[6]]
#      j
# i     A Caa
#   B   1   1
#   Ba  1   0
#   Caa 0   1
```